# Not able to show multiple timer in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-state

I am creating a Chat Polling feature and in chat polling I am showing timer for every new poll. Everything is **working fine for the first poll** but when I create a 2nd poll form backend new poll is creatine good with new question but the first poll timer is also reflecting in 2nd poll.

**This is PollWidget to show Question with Timer.**

```
class PollWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  final Poll poll;
  final disabled;
  final PollCallbacks callbacks;

  PollWidget({required this.poll, required this.callbacks, this.disabled = false});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => PollWidgetState();
}
```

```
class PollWidgetState extends State<PollWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: AbsorbPointer(
          absorbing: widget.disabled,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: _getChildren(widget.poll.question!),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _getChildren(Question question) {
    List<Widget> children = List.empty(growable: true);

      children.add(_getSpace());
      children.add(
        TimerWidget(maxSeconds: widget.poll.maxSeconds, onFinish: () {
          widget.callbacks.onTimeFinished(widget.poll);
          setState(() {
            isPollEnded = true;
          });
          },
        ),
      );
    return children;
  }
}
```

**Here is TimerWidget class to show timere in poll.**

```
class TimerWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  final int maxSeconds;
  final Function onFinish;

  TimerWidget({required this.maxSeconds, required this.onFinish});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TimerWidgetState();
}
```

```
class _TimerWidgetState extends State<TimerWidget> {
  int currentSeconds = 0;

  Timer? timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentSeconds = widget.maxSeconds > 0 ? widget.maxSeconds : 0;

    if (currentSeconds > 0) {
      timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {

        setState(() {
          currentSeconds -= 1;
        });
        if (currentSeconds <= 0) {
          timer.cancel();
          widget.onFinish();
        }

      });
    }

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    timer?.cancel();
    timer = null;
  }

  String getTime() {

    if (currentSeconds >= 86400) {
      int days = currentSeconds~/(24 * 3600);
      int n = currentSeconds % (24 * 3600);
      int hour = n ~/ 3600;
      return "${days.prefixZero()} Days ${hour.prefixZero()} ${Strings.hours}";

    } else if (currentSeconds >= 3600) {
      int hours = currentSeconds~/3600;
      int minutes = (currentSeconds % 3600) ~/ 60;
      int seconds = (currentSeconds% 3600) % 60;
      return "${hours.prefixZero()}:${minutes.prefixZero()}:${seconds.prefixZero()} ${Strings.hours}";

    } else {
      int minutes = currentSeconds ~/60;
      int seconds = currentSeconds % 60;
      return "${minutes.prefixZero()}:${seconds.prefixZero()} ${(currentSeconds >= 60) ? Strings.minutes : Strings.seconds}";
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      Text("${getTime()}" , style: TextStyle(color: Color(AppColors.alert)),);

}
```

[Please see the output here i have created 2nd poll of 2 min but it is showing above poll time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL3Fd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try to add **Key** in Timer Widget?

```
    class TimerWidget extends StatefulWidget {        
          final int maxSeconds;
          final Function onFinish;
          Key key;    
        
          TimerWidget({required this.maxSeconds, required this.onFinish, Key key});
        
          @override
          State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TimerWidgetState();
        }
```

Use Timer Widget Like This

```
List<Widget> _getChildren(Question question) {
    List<Widget> children = List.empty(growable: true);

      children.add(_getSpace());
      children.add(
        TimerWidget(
      key:UniqueKey(),
       maxSeconds: widget.poll.maxSeconds, onFinish: () {
          widget.callbacks.onTimeFinished(widget.poll);
          setState(() {
            isPollEnded = true;
          });
          },
        ),
      );
    return children;
  }
```

Comment: I have one more problem related to it In PollWidgetState I have a list `List<Option> selectedOptions = List.empty(growable: true);` which is also getting clear for 1st poll on 2nd poll creating.